# XSLT - Count distinct period date values for each employee and add up all counts for a total

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm not even sure I phrased the question correctly. I need to get a count of how many records are displayed in a report generated by [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt) and display it in a footer row that contains various totals. The count I'm looking for is how many retro period rows are displayed in the report.

Each employee has a node in [xml](/questions/tagged/xml). Within each employee's node, there are child nodes which may contain zero to many payments which have associated retro pay period date nodes. An employee may have multiple nodes for the same retro pay period. In the report, each employee should have 1 line per retro pay period. So, to get a count of how many of these retro lines are supposed to be displayed in the report, I need to only count the unique/distinct retro period dates for each employee and then take all those counts and add them up for the total amount of retro rows displayed at the end in the footer row.

Example XML:

```
<Report_Entry>
  <Worker Descriptor="Mick Mouse (00001)">
    <ID type="Employee_ID">00001</ID>
  </Worker>
  <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
  <Worker Descriptor="Don Duck (On Leave) (00002)">
    <ID type="Employee_ID">00002</ID>
  </Worker>
  <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Retro_Prd_End>2022-12-31</Retro_Prd_End>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
  <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Retro_Prd_End>2022-12-31</Retro_Prd_End>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
  <Worker Descriptor="Adam Ant (00003)">
    <ID type="Employee_ID">00003</ID>
  </Worker>
  <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-15</Retro_Prd_End>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
  <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-15</Retro_Prd_End>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
  <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-28</Retro_Prd_End>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
  <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Retro_Prd_End>2023-03-15</Retro_Prd_End>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
</Report_Entry>
```

In the example, the count I'm expecting is 4 (Mick has 0, Don has 1 unique Retro_Prd_End, and Adam has 3).

The following hasn't worked:
1.

```
<xsl:variable name="CountERSRetroLines" select="count(distinct-values(concat(Report_Data/Report_Entry/Worker/ID[@type='Employee_ID'],'|',../Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range/Retro_Prd_End)))" />
```

2. 

```
<xsl:variable name="CountERSRetroLines" select="count(distinct-values(Report_Data/Report_Entry/Worker/ID[@type='Employee_ID'][distinct-values(../Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range/Retro_Prd_End)]))" />
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XPath 2.0 solution:

```
sum(//Report_Entry ! count(distinct-values(./Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range/Retro_Prd_End)))
```

Using the [Simple Mapping Operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-map-operator) `!` to iterate over each of the `Report_Entry`, count their `Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range` distinct values. And calculate the [`sum()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sum) of those counts.

Comment: I didn't know about that! Thank you! I hope it's OK to ask... how would I further count only the ones where the sum amount per employee's Retro_Prd_End was != 0?
I tried the following, but it returned 0:
sum(//Report_Entry ! count(distinct-values(./Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range/Retro_Prd_End[number(sum(Result_Line_Amount))!=0])))

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Your predicate is using `Result_Line_Amount`, which I don't see in the example XML. Assuming that your XML has that element with a value, and you want to exclude the ones equal to zero from the count, I would use a predicate of: `[not(Result_Line_Amount=0 )]` or `[not(sum(Result_Line_Amount)=0 )]` depending upon your data and what you are trying to exclude. The difference between `not()` and `!=`  can be confusing until you understand that `!=` is set comparison and may seem confusing if you don't know that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2273853/14419

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. `Result_Line_Amount` is a sibling of `Retro_Prd_End`. Example XML:
`<Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Result_Line_Amount>10.50</Result_Line_Amount>
    <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-15</Retro_Prd_End>
  </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>`

Comment: `sum(//wd:Report_Entry ! count(distinct-values(./wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range/wd:Retro_Prd_End[not(sum(../wd:Result_Line_Amount)=0 )])))` gets me closer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example is not provide. So, I am shooting from the hip.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Worker Descriptor="Mick Mouse (00001)">
            <ID type="Employee_ID">00001</ID>
        </Worker>
        <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
        </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Worker Descriptor="Don Duck (On Leave) (00002)">
            <ID type="Employee_ID">00002</ID>
        </Worker>
        <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
            <Retro_Prd_End>2022-12-31</Retro_Prd_End>
        </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
        <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
            <Retro_Prd_End>2022-12-31</Retro_Prd_End>
        </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Worker Descriptor="Adam Ant (00003)">
            <ID type="Employee_ID">00003</ID>
        </Worker>
        <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
            <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-15</Retro_Prd_End>
        </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
        <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
            <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-15</Retro_Prd_End>
        </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
        <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
            <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-28</Retro_Prd_End>
        </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
        <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
            <Retro_Prd_End>2023-03-15</Retro_Prd_End>
        </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry"
                                group-by="Worker/ID">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"
                          order="ascending"/>

                <xsl:variable name="count-Total"
                              select="count(distinct-values(current-group()/Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range/Retro_Prd_End))"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/*"/>
                    <Total>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$count-Total"/>
                    </Total>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Worker Descriptor="Mick Mouse (00001)">
      <ID type="Employee_ID">00001</ID>
    </Worker>
    <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range/>
    <Total>0</Total>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Worker Descriptor="Don Duck (On Leave) (00002)">
      <ID type="Employee_ID">00002</ID>
    </Worker>
    <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
      <Retro_Prd_End>2022-12-31</Retro_Prd_End>
    </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
      <Retro_Prd_End>2022-12-31</Retro_Prd_End>
    </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Total>1</Total>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Worker Descriptor="Adam Ant (00003)">
      <ID type="Employee_ID">00003</ID>
    </Worker>
    <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
      <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-15</Retro_Prd_End>
    </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
      <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-15</Retro_Prd_End>
    </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
      <Retro_Prd_End>2023-02-28</Retro_Prd_End>
    </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
      <Retro_Prd_End>2023-03-15</Retro_Prd_End>
    </Payroll_Result_Lines_within_Date_Range>
    <Total>3</Total>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```